# oracle sql split string to rows (alphabet in sequential order) - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I am looking for a oracle sql solution for the below problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option (as union of 3 different cases).

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'A-D'      from dual union all
  3     select 'J-K'      from dual union all
  4     select 'X-20'     from dual union all
  5     select 'XX-20542' from dual union all
  6     select 'A/B'      from dual union all
  7     select 'J/K'      from dual
  8    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  -- A-D option:
 10  select col,
 11         chr(ascii(substr(col, 1, 1)) + column_value - 1) res
 12  from test cross join
 13    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 14                        connect by level <= ascii(substr(col, -1)) - ascii(substr(col, 1, 1)) + 1
 15                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 16  where regexp_like(col, '[[:alpha:]]-[[:alpha:]]')
 17  -- XX-20542 option:
 18  union all
 19  select col, 'No action / ignore'
 20  from test
 21  where regexp_like(col, '[[:alpha:]]+-\d+')
 22  -- A/B option:
 23  union all
 24  select col,
 25         regexp_substr(col, '[[:alpha:]]', 1, column_value)
 26  from test cross join
 27    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 28                        connect by level <= ascii(substr(col, -1)) - ascii(substr(col, 1, 1)) + 1
 29                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 30  where regexp_like(col, '[[:alpha:]]/[[:alpha:]]');
```

Result:

```
COL      RES
-------- ------------------
A-D      A
A-D      B
A-D      C
A-D      D
J-K      J
J-K      K
X-20     No action / ignore
XX-20542 No action / ignore
A/B      A
A/B      B
J/K      J
J/K      K

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single recursive query:

```sql
WITH ranges (value, min_value, skip, max_value) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^([A-Z])([[:punct:]])([A-Z])$', 1, 1, 'i', 1),
         CASE REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^([A-Z])([[:punct:]])([A-Z])$', 1, 1, 'i', 2)
         WHEN '-'
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
         END,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^([A-Z])([[:punct:]])([A-Z])$', 1, 1, 'i', 3)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         CASE skip
         WHEN 0
         THEN CHR(ASCII(min_value) + 1)
         ELSE max_value
         END,
         skip,
         max_value
  FROM   ranges
  WHERE  min_value < max_value
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET rn
SELECT value,
       COALESCE(min_value, 'ignore') AS result
FROM   ranges
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'A-D'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'J-K'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'XX-Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y-ZZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B/C'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E/E'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F/H'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | RESULT |
> | --- | --- |
> | A-D | A |
> | A-D | B |
> | A-D | C |
> | A-D | D |
> | B/C | B |
> | B/C | C |
> | E/E | E |
> | F/H | F |
> | F/H | H |
> | J-K | J |
> | J-K | K |
> | XX-Y | ignore |
> | Y-ZZ | ignore |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=75b578d2a5f8e073438f5155f90894f4)*

Comment: I really appreciate your support!
In this case, the result is not correct, if the Value is (A/C) then Result should be (A&C) not (A,B,C)

VALUE RESULT
A/C A
A/C B
A/C C